# Using Go CD with .NET

Tags: c#, .net, git, deployment, go-cd

I would like to use [Go CD](http://www.go.cd) with .NET Web API projects and Git.

I like the idea of promoting a specific build artifact to some environments via pipelines. Currently we're using TeamCity and branching in Git. We use MSBuild to build and deploy with a specific Config Transform (Test, Staging, Live).

Our MSBuild command line arguments are the following:

```
/p:Configuration=%DeployConfiguration% /p:Platform=AnyCPU /t:WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:DeleteExistingFiles=True /p:publishUrl=%DeployPath%
```

- `%DeployConfiguration%` is a parameter for each environment; Test, Staging, Live and uses .NET Config Transforms to transform the Web.config for a specified environment.
- `%DeployPath%` is a parameter for each project for each environment. So AuthAPI Live would be something like: `\\liveServer\path\to\AuthAPI\`.

My one question regarding this is: How to use a specific environment config (using .NET Config Transforms) when the build artifact is promoted to the next stage in the pipeline? So for example, when the build is promoted to testing environment I want to use Web.Test.config, but when promoted to staging environment I want to use Web.Staging.config, etc.

Also I would like to know if you have any experience using Go CD with .NET projects?

Comment: Do you use Go to build as well?

Answer (score 0):

I have not experience using Go CD with .NET projects, but maybe my advise will be helpfull.

1.Create TransformStaging.csproj file with content:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Transform" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets" />
    <Target Name="Transform">
        <Copy SourceFiles="$(Source)" DestinationFiles="$(Source).tmp"/>
        <TransformXml Source="$(Source).tmp" Transform="Web.Staging.config" Destination="$(Source)" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

2.Call msbuild with

```
msbuild.exe TransformStaging.csproj /p:Source=$configFilePath
```

Comment: The MSBuild command line does a Config Transform for the correct environment (specified as a parameter in TeamCity). I'm just wondering how to put an appropriate config file when Go CD uses build artifacts (already transformed configs)?

Answer (score 0):

There are parts of configuration that are environment specific (you will have a different db connection for Dev,QA, UAT, Production environments for example), and then there are configurations settings that do not change from one environment to the other, lets call these application specific config values.  Example of those would be perhaps you setup a logger component and disregarding what environment app is in you want the log files to go to a certain folder, c:\logs.

I would suggest keep application specific settings in your App.Config file (these are deployed from one env to other using xcopy), but the ones that are environment specific, take out.  Separate deployment of environment configuration from your app deployment.  These should be deployed to machine when it is built/configured.

Environment specific variables can be set stored in OS Environment Variables, Machine.config, known file location etc.

That way your app just has to query: Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyAppDBName")
And Dev, QA, and Production environments/servers will have different answers.

And you will be deploying the same binaries across each environment.

Answer (score 0):

**Nermin Dibek** is pointing the correct way to do things, but I will like to add something more specific to his answer.

I implemented the process in my organization and after you migrate to Environment Variables ***(With this you avoid commit the Configuration file that contains Secret Keys(Security Leaks))***, in GoCD there is a place call **environment** that will allow you to customize the pipeline where you are running. For example in my Org I have Staging env, Testing env, Prod and you can go on as many as you like, this give you a nice feature because you can assign to differents environment different agents and different pipelines, for example we are running only unit test in Testing so I put the slowest agent for that task.